# React / Kestrel settings for admin folder

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kestrel

I'm trying to setup new location rule for the "admin" folder for my reactjs SPA application. It uses Kestrel as a web server and Nginx as a proxy.

I have already one configuration, which is working fine with redirection all requests to the index.html file, which contains necessary javascript logic:

```
location /favicon.ico { 
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; 
proxy_http_version 1.1; 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive; 
proxy_set_header Host $host;    
} 

location ~ ^/(fonts|img|js|lib|script|style)/ { 
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; 
proxy_http_version 1.1; 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive; 
proxy_set_header Host $host;    
} 

location / { 
try_files $uri /index.html; 
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; 
proxy_http_version 1.1; 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive; 
proxy_set_header Host $host; 
}
```

Now I need to add rule for /admin/ folder which will route all requests to the /admin/index.html, once /admin/ is a part of the path, but the following is not work:

```
location /admin/ { 
try_files /index.html $uri; 
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; 
proxy_http_version 1.1; 
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive; 
proxy_set_header Host $host; 
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, 
Anton

Comment: Resolved by removing Kestrel app for SPA, final version looks as follows:         location /admin {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;  
    try_files $uri /admin/index.html;
    index index.html;
        }

Comment: Note : comments are supposed to be temporary and used to add some clarifications, they may be cleaned and removed at any moment. If you make an answer out of it, you can self-accept it, and your solution could benefit to other people.